# Defining a default key in a many-to-many relation

Tags: django, many-to-many

I am subclassing the AbstractUser this way:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    customer = models.ManyToManyField(Customer)
    default_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

One User can have different Customer's accounts, and of course a Customer account will have plenty of Users.

But I want to add a "default_customer" field that will be changed in the user interface.

Doing the above, I got an error:

```
profiles.MyUser.customer: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'MyUser.customer' clashes with reverse accessor for 'MyUser.default_customer'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'MyUser.customer' or 'MyUser.default_customer'.
profiles.MyUser.default_customer: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'MyUser.default_customer' clashes with reverse accessor for 'MyUser.customer'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'MyUser.default_customer' or 'MyUser.customer'.
```

I can add a related_name to my ManyToMany and ForeignKey fields, but is my design OK?

Comment: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'MyUser.customer' or 'MyUser.default_customer'.

Comment: Yep, I asked the wrong question: is my design OK?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the related name to navigate from Customer to MyUser, django is generating one automatically that clashes in your two relationships. To fix that specify one:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    customer = models.ManyToManyField(Customer, related_name='users')
    default_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='default_users')
```